# How to get the 64bit data from an XML file to a string in Groovy

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

How can I reliably get the 64bit data from an XML file to a byte[] and then compare that with a string? The following code fails as it seems the whitespace is causing the assert to fail. The goal is for the assert to pass.

*Note that it is important that we have it in the form of byte[] at somepoint, but not that the comparison be via strings*

```
<Contents>VGVzdGluZyBURSBzZXNzaW9uIGNvbnRhaW5pbmcgQ29tcGxldGUgUGVyc29uIEEgYW5kIENvbXBs
                ZXRlIEVxdWlwbWVudCBCLg0KDQpUZXN0IFRlc3QNCg0KUmVmZXJlbmNlcyBDb21wbGV0ZSBQbGFj
                ZSBB
            </Contents>
```

---

```
byte[] byteData = document.Contents.text()
assert 'VGVzdGluZyBURSBzZXNzaW9uIGNvbnRhaW5pbmcgQ29tcGxldGUgUGVyc29uIEEgYW5kIENvbXBs'+
                'ZXRlIEVxdWlwbWVudCBCLg0KDQpUZXN0IFRlc3QNCg0KUmVmZXJlbmNlcyBDb21wbGV0ZSBQbGFj'+
                'ZSBB' == new String(byteData)
```

Comment: @tim_yates I'm no data type expert, but I believe this is the text editor showing the 64bit encoded data as random letters, no? The values compared in the assert both "look" the same when printed by JUnit or in a println, but they aren't ==.

Comment: No, to be in xml, it can't be a binary object. This is a textual encoding of something... Do you know how it's encoded?

Comment: Again from someone ignorant on the subtleties on data, I know it is Base 64 encoded data. I believe the original data is likely ascii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base 64 data is a special encoding of text to ASCII to be URL friendly (historically)

EDIT thanks to comment below, actually base64 was to encode data to send via for email

to extract text from your data, do this:

```
new String(
'VGVzdGluZyBURSBzZXNzaW9uIGNvbnRhaW5pbmcgQ29tcGxldGUgUGVyc29uIEEgYW5kIENvbXBsZXRlIEVxdWlwbWVudCBCLg0KDQpUZXN0IFRlc3QNCg0KUmVmZXJlbmNlcyBDb21wbGV0ZSBQbGFjZSBB')
.decodeBase64()
)
```

result starts with 'ession containing Complete Person A and Complete Equipment B.'

from http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2009/11/groovy-goodness-base64-encoding.html

Comment: Actually Base64 is older than wide-spread URL use. As far as I know it's initially been designed to transfer data across the email system which wasn't entirely 8-bit clean back then (i.e. some servers simply set all the 8th bits to 0).

Comment: Interesting, it looks like the 'S' was dropped during the encoding process from "Session containing Complete ...". Maybe the reason they weren't == was that the beginning was dropped.